# underscore remove object from array containing null values on some properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, oop, underscore.js

given an array [{"id":"66859","value":"Discontinued"},{"id":null,"value":null}], i want to remove the objects that have id value of null.

is it possible using underscore? or any other javascript method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `reject` function in underscore.js. It returns array without the object you want to delete.

```
 arr = _.reject(arr, function(item){ return (item.id === null || item.id === ??); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = data.filter((item)=>{return item.id});
```

Comment: Hooray for recommending an ES5 standard feature!

Comment: you could even write it like const arr = data.filter( item => item.id )